# Breadth First Binary Tree Search using TreeNodes Extending Comparable

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, comparable

I'm having issues implementing my breadth first traversal for my binary tree. I keep getting a class cast exception at these two lines:

```
        if(node.left != null) queue.offer(node.left);
        if(node.right != null) queue.offer(node.right);
```

The exception says: "TreeNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable" 
I need the extends Comparable for other methods this class, any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

```
public class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {

private TreeNode<E> left;
private TreeNode<E> right;
private E value;


public TreeNode(E value) 
{
    this.value = value;
}

    public void breadthFirstTraversal(TreeNode<E> root, ArrayList<E> breadthList)
{
    Queue<TreeNode<E>> queue = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode<E>>();
    if (root == null)
        return;
    queue.clear();
    queue.offer(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        TreeNode<E> node = queue.remove();
        breadthList.add(node.value);
        if(node.left != null) queue.offer(node.left);
        if(node.right != null) queue.offer(node.right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
public class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

This only says that the `E` in `TreeNode<E>` should implement `Comparable`, not that the `TreeNode` itself should. For that you would need to make `TreeNode` implement `Comparable` in the usual fashion:

```
public class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<TreeNode<E>>
```

And add the appropriate overrides.